# Проблема с кодировкой CP 866

Tags: java, minecraft

В консоли майнкрафт сервера вместо ошибки пишется это:

```
╨Ю╤И╨╕╨▒╨║╨░! ╨Э╨╡╨╕╨╖╨▓╨╡╤Б╤В╨╜╨░╤П ╨║╨╛╨╝╨░╨╜╨┤╨░.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой щелкнуть по верхней части окна -> Свойства -> в открывшемся окне в поле Шрифт выбрать Lucida Console и нажать кнопку ОК.

Либо попробовать сменить кодировку окна консоли при помощи chcp
1251 Кириллица, 866 DOS, 65001 UTF-8